# ReadFile ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE after several Serial Port reads

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, serial-port

I am new to the serial library on windows so any guidance is greatly appreciated. I have a microcontroller plugged into a USB port and it constantly sends data over UART. An example of what should be received is:

ADC value 1: 848 ADC value 2: 972 ADC interrupt count: 2300

(pause)

ADC value 1: 849 ADC value 2: 971 ADC interrupt count: 2301

The program itself has a thread on the GUI, and once the user selects a COM port, a file is created with the handle name *hCom*. A new thread is created and *hCom* is passed to it. I've attempted to use an infinite while-loop on the new thread to constantly read the port (I will implement proper checking conditions later). The ReadFile function reads one byte at a time and prints them out to the screen. This continusouly loops. However, no more data is received after the first set (val 1, val 2, int count) is sent.

The creation of the file and thread spawn is here:

```c
HANDLE hCom = CreateFile(szComPort,
                                         GENERIC_READ |
                                         GENERIC_WRITE, // desired access should be read&write
                                         0,                          // COM port must be opened in non-sharing mode
                                         NULL,                       // don't care about the security
                                         OPEN_EXISTING,              // IMPORTANT: must use OPEN_EXISTING for a COM port
                                         0,                          // usually overlapped but non-overlapped for existance test
                                         NULL);
                if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hCom) {
                    MessageBox(hwnd, "This port is not available or is in use.", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
                    return WndProc(hwnd, WM_CREATE, wParam, lParam);
                }
                AppendText(hOut, "CONNECTED TO " + std::string(szComPort) + "\r\n");
                DWORD myThreadID;
                CreateThread(NULL, 0, serialHandler, &hCom, 0, &myThreadID);
return WndProc(hwnd, WM_CREATE, wParam, lParam);
```

Here is my thread handler:

```c
DWORD WINAPI serialHandler(LPVOID lpParameter) {
    HANDLE &hCom = *((HANDLE *) lpParameter);
    SetCommState(hCom, &dcbSerialParams);
    COMMTIMEOUTS tMyTimeOuts =  {
            MAXDWORD, //  DWORD ReadIntervalTimeout;
            0, //  DWORD ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier;
            10000,    //  DWORD ReadTotalTimeoutConstant;
            1000,     //  DWORD WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier;
            1000,     //  DWORD WriteTotalTimeoutConstant;
    };
    if (!SetCommTimeouts(hCom, &tMyTimeOuts))
        printf("setting port time-outs.");

    std::string sb = "";
    DWORD dwEventMask, dwSize = 0;


    while (1) {
        char szBuf;
        DWORD dwIncommingReadSize;
        do {
            int error = ReadFile(hCom, &szBuf, 1, &dwIncommingReadSize, NULL);
            if (error !=0) {
                if (dwIncommingReadSize > 0) {
                    dwSize += dwIncommingReadSize;
                    sb += szBuf;
                    printf("%c", szBuf);
                    sb = "";
                }
            } else {
                printf("No Data Received - ");
                DWORD lasterror = GetLastError();
                lasterror = GetLastError();
            }
        } while (dwIncommingReadSize > 0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Here is a part of WM_CREATE that caused me issues

```c
hCom = CreateFile(szComPort,
                                  GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, // desired access should be read&write
                                  0,                          // COM port must be opened in non-sharing mode
                                  NULL,                       // don't care about the security
                                  OPEN_EXISTING,              // IMPORTANT: must use OPEN_EXISTING for a COM port
                                  0,                          // usually overlapped but non-overlapped for existance test
                                  NULL);                      // always NULL for a general purpose COM port

                if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hCom) {
                    if ((ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED) == GetLastError()) {   // then it exists and currently opened
                        wsprintf(szComPort, _T("&COM%d (in use)"), i);
                        AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, COM_PORT_MESSAGE_BASE + i, szComPort);
                    }
                } else {   // COM port exists
                    wsprintf(szComPort, _T("COM%d"), i);
                    AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, COM_PORT_MESSAGE_BASE + i, szComPort);
                    CloseHandle(hCom);
                }
```

The actual output is:

ADC valu1: 848
ADC value 2: 972
ADC interrupt count: 2879
ANo Data Received - No Data Received - No Data Received -

And so on. The variable lasterror in serialhandler returns 6, which is ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE. I'm not sure why the handle goes from valid to invalid after one "set" of reads.

Comment: `CreateThread(NULL, 0, serialHandler, &hCom, 0, &myThreadID);` FYI, that's a *terrible* idea. `hCom` is a automatic (local) variable the is gone the moment the containing scope (in this case it seems to be your wndproc switch) is exited. Lord only knows what complete gibberish the  thread will eventually land on once other code starts writing on that stack memory. And that's *guaranteed* to happen, because you actually use a *reference* type for `hCom` in your thread procedure. Unrelated, bust just to pound salt in the wound, you're leaking your thread handle too.

Comment: Wow you're absolutely correct. Let me give that a quick fix and get back to you.

Comment: I've updated the code to re-initialize the com handle in the thread function. Unfortunately I get an INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE thrown back at me and I'm not sure why, because I closed the handle earlier.

Comment: You know WhozCraig, I need to thoroughly look through my code. I had another file handle open. Your suggestion fixed my issue and I have no problem receiving the data now. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Since you're already pinned hook, line, and sinker to winapi, I won't bother with the suggestion to use `std::thread` and friends for stuff like this.  It is less error prone, and more intuitive in my opinion, but frankly its biggest benefit (code portability) is meaningless in this situation. Anyway, best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the file handle open in another part of my code and forgot to close it. This led to issues when I tried to open the port and it no longer existed, and my readfile function didn't work. Make sure to check all your instances of createfile.

In specific, the reason why my code did not work was twofold. First, I passed a local copy of hCom onto another thread's stack.

```
CreateThread(NULL, 0, serialHandler, &hCom, 0, &myThreadID);
```

Then I returned to the same function in order to re-draw the GUI (I wanted to update my menubar to show that a connection was established).

```
return WndProc(hwnd, WM_CREATE, wParam, lParam);
```

Inside WM_CREATE is a port scan which re-opens all ports to check if they are open.

```
hCom = CreateFile(szComPort,
                                  GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, // desired access should be read&write
                                  0,                          // COM port must be opened in non-sharing mode
                                  NULL,                       // don't care about the security
                                  OPEN_EXISTING,              // IMPORTANT: must use OPEN_EXISTING for a COM port
                                  0,                          // usually overlapped but non-overlapped for existance test
                                  NULL);                      // always NULL for a general purpose COM port
```

This interfered with the earlier thread, since it was using the same handle to gather data. This is why it would work for a little while, until the other thread ran and re-used the COM port. I fixed this issue by removing the return function, passing an integer to the new thread, and opening the COM port in the new thread.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked. The issue isn't with this answer as much as it is with the question. There's simply no way to see from the question, what the issue is. That's why we ask for a [mcve] if at all possible. Not only does this have a higher chance of producing a valuable Q&A, but it also trains you to isolate a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I've rolled back the question and updated the answer.